# Mapping template / instance tables with NHibernate

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to use NHibernate with a database that is conceptually equivalent to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Survey(ID int, SurveyName varchar(max))
CREATE TABLE Question(ID int, QuestionText varchar(max))
CREATE TABLE SurveyQuestion(SurveyID int, QuestionID int, Order int, Required bit)

CREATE TABLE AnsweredSurvey(ID int, SurveyID int, AnsweredBy varchar(max))
CREATE TABLE AnsweredQuestion(ID int, AnsweredSurveyID int, QuestionID int, Answer varchar(max))
```

The AnsweredSurvey/AnsweredQuestion tables are populated from the template tables whenever a user takes a survey.  This is performed by another application, so I am only reading data from these tables.  I have no control over the data or the schema.

The entity I'm having trouble with is:

```
class AnsweredQuestion {
    int Id;
    AnsweredSurvey AnsweredSurvey;
    SurveyQuestion SurveyQuestion;
}
```

Note that it has a property of type SurveyQuestion, not plain Question.  I would like to be able to populate this property based on the QuestionID of AnsweredQuestion, and the SurveyID of the parent AnsweredSurvey.  Is there a straightforward way to map these entities this way in NHibernate?  I'm using FluentNHibernate, but a pure HBM solution would at least point me in the right direction.

For completeness, here are the other entities:

```
class Survey {
    int Id;
    string SurveyName;
    IEnumerable<SurveyQuestion> SurveyQuestions;
}

class Question {
    int Id;
    string QuestionText;
}

class SurveyQuestion {
    Survey Survey;
    Question Question;
    int Order;
    bool Required;
}

class AnsweredSurvey {
    int Id;
    Survey Survey;
    IEnumerable<AnsweredQuestion> AnsweredQuestions;
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your model and the schema is mapping the SurveyQuestion entity/table as it has a composite key which you want to map to two many-to-one associations. This can be done but i have never used it.

Example using fluent nhibernate:

```
SurveyQuestionMap()
{
   CompositeId() 
     .KeyReference(x => x.Survey, "SurveyID")
     .KeyReference(x => x.Question, "QuestionID");

  // the rest
}
```

The other classes should be no problem. 
For example:

```
 AnsweredSurveyMap()
 { 
     Id(x => x.Id)
     References(x => x.Survey);
     HasMany(c => c.AnsweredQuestions)
       .Inverse()
       .Cascade.All()
       .KeyColumn("AnsweredSurveyID");
}
```

You might need to specify more key columns/tables depending on the configured fluent nhibernate convention settings.

Comment: The problem is, I want to reference SurveyQuestion from AnsweredQuestion, but AnsweredQuestion does not have the SurveyID.  In order to get the SurveyID I have to follow the association to AnsweredSurvey, but I can't figure out how to do that declaratively in a mapping class.